# How i can fix JSONAPI::Serializable::UndefinedSerializableClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json-api, jsonapi-resources

How I can fix:

```
ERROR: JSONAPI::Serializable::UndefinedSerializableClass: No 
serializable class defined for Post
app/controllers/api/v1/posts_controller.rb:20:in `index'
```

Using this gems:

```
gem 'jsonapi_suite'
gem 'jsonapi-rails'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set a `class` argument to `render_jsonapi`.

```
# app/controllers/api/v1/posts_controller.rb
module Api
  module V1
    class PostsController < Api::V1::ApplicationController
      # ...

      def index
        posts = Post.all
        render_jsonapi(posts, class: { Post: Api::V1::SerializablePost })
      end

      # ...
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I get no such method jsonapi_render - any ideas how to pass class in the later versions?

Comment: @Hackeron No, I don't know. Sorry.